# Issue booting into windows after Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, testdisk, bootrepair

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkIwy.jpg)

I was trying to install ubuntu from a flash drive but ran into some issues during the installation since it was not showing all my disk partitions.

After trying to troubleshoot the problem I think I made it worse as I can't access the windows boot menu anymore. I am currently using the Ubuntu live version and I am afraid to finish installation.

- I used testdisk and found that I have several partitions marked as deleted. Thankfully I can access the partitions through testdisk and recover some files. But I was wondering: is there is some way to fix the disk completely and be able to boot back up normally?
- I also used boot repair to see if the issue could be fixed and I got this information that could be useful but unfortunately I do not understand: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nGGs6YTsXR/

I am also attaching a screenshot of what testdisk is showing.

[image: Testdsik Screenshot]
[image]
[image: Windows partitions 1]
[image: Windows partition 2]

Comment: Hi again! Taking up where we left. You've got a big 234GB unallocated space that you're going to format with Windows installer (it'll be formatted as NTFS) and install Windows 10 on it. Don't fret, you can install Windows 10 without a licence, but once it's installed, and up-and-running, you'll be able to edit the BCD (Boot Configuration Data), enumerate your other Windows partitions (there should be only one), and decide which one is default (we'll choose your existing Windows), then we'll proceed to delete the Windows 10 partition THE RIGHT WAY. How about that?

Comment: Sounds good. If I format only that partition the rest of the days won't be lost correct?

Comment: When I try formatting the indicated space I get a warning that says"Windows can't be installed to this disk. The select disk had an MBR partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks. Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. The selected disk has the maximum number of partitions of this type."

Comment: OK. Which of those partitions has your current Windows installation on it? It's hard to say from the pictures. It must be either partition 2 or 4 (my bet is on 2, but I'm a lousy gambler...). We are going to have to shrink that system partition a little bit to temporarily install Windows 10 on it, and we are going to use diskpart for that, but we need to be sure which one it is.

Comment: That gamble would've paid off, it is partition 2. The problem is that even if I tried formating the entire partition I would get the same warning about the MBR partition table, but the maximum number of partitions warning would go away. Also, my problem originated because I was trying to install Ubuntu but my disk was not showing the partitions in the installation process so I followed this instructions, hopefully this gives you insight into what the problem is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/287352/ubuntu-13-04-installation-does-not-detect-windows-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the exchange of comments with Emilio since the beginning of this thread, here's what I propose.

You're going to boot from the Windows USB installer. You are going to choose Repair instead of Install, then proceed to Advanced, then Command Line.

Once in Command Line, type "diskpart" (press Enter)

Type "list disk" (Enter)

Type "select disk 0" (Enter)

Type "list volume" (Enter)

Type "select volume x" (where x is your partition number 4 on disk 0; press Enter)

Type "extend size=234300" (Enter)

If all goes well, after a short while, diskpart will return a message like "Diskpart successfully extended the volume". If you get an error message saying that it couldn't, try the "extend" command with a little less in size, like 234200 (MB). You'll have a little empty space at the end of your drive, that you can merge with the existing adjacent partition later, from Windows's Disk Management.

That way, you won't exceed the limit set by Microsoft in terms of number of partitions. You'lle then be able to shrink the system partition (the one containing Windows), create a new one where we'll temporarily install Windows 10 to solve your booting issues.

Maybe getting rid of this fourth unnecessary partition would suffice to boot from Windows. Worth a try, but I doubt it.

EDIT: I posted this as an answer so as not to multiply comments...

Comment: I was able to extend partition 4. How do I do the other steps?

Comment: On diskpart, you are going to select that partition #2, and this time, you're going to shrink it by 50GB, with the following command: "shrink desired=50000". This is where it could become tricky, because although you've plenty of free space on that partition, it's not evenly distributed, and you could get an error message saying that diskpart couldn't complete the operation due to "lack of space". In fact, diskpart won't have been able to locate enough free ADJACENT segments of your partition to total 50GB, so you'll have to try again with a small number. It's kind of hit-or-miss, here.

Comment: When I tried resizing it it said "The volume you have selected to shrink may be corrupted. Use chkdsk to fix the corruption problem, and then try to shrink the volume again". I ran chkdsk, tried again and got the same message

Comment: OK, let's try something else. You're going to download Gparted (free, here: https://gparted.org/), and burn it onto another USB stick (I hope you've got one to spare... It's not that big anyway), boot from the Gparted USB, leave all the language and keyboard settings as default, and once in the GUI, select your disk from the drop-down menu on top, select your partition #2, and manually shrink it by 50GB with your mouse (click on the rightmost extremity, and drag it toward the center of the line until you get about 50GB of free space on the right of your mouse pointer. Click on the green check.

Comment: When trying to boot I got a message saying "EFI USB Device (Generic Flash Disk) has been blocked by the current security policy"

Comment: You need to go into your UEFI and turn Secure Boot off. I had come to think your PC had a BIOS, but apparently it's not the case. In the Security tab in the UEFI, you'll find a way to disable Secure Boot. Save settings and reboot, on the USB Gparted. It should be OK. You can enable Secure Boot back on after you've settled all your current issues...

Comment: Gparted is currently running and shrinking partition #2. What should be my next step? Boot into windows install and attempt installing in the new partition created from the shrunk space?

Comment: Good to know Gparted is doing its job, and yes, you're right, you have to try and install Windows 10 on the new partition you'll create from the unallocated space Gparted is currently making. Once you've installed Windows 10 (fingers crossed), you can set your current Windows installation as default, and we'll find a way to get rid of Windows 10 before you have to activate it.

Comment: When I tried installing windows in that new partition I got the same error that says "Windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed on GPT disks".

Comment: You'll have to go back to diskpart, then. Close the Windows installer with the red X top right, confirm, then go back to Repair, Advanced, Command Line, then "diskpart", then select the newly create partition, and type "create partition primary", then "active", then "format fs=ntfs quick", then "assign", then "exit" (to exit diskpart), "exit" again (to exit Command Line), then reboot your PC on the USB installer. There might be the need to re-enable Secure Boot along the way, but maybe not right way. If you can, check in your BIOS/UEFI that SATA is under AHCI.

Comment: The created partition is not showing but the 50GB form partition #2 was definitely taken out. Should I try creating a partition/volume with diskpart?

Comment: If you now have a 50GB free space adjacent to your Windows partition, yes.

Comment: I think resizing the partition made all the files in that partition disappear which is unfortunate. Also even after following those instructions keep getting the same error.

Comment: Diskpart wouldn't have shrunk that partition by deleting any files. It would have returned an error if resizing your partition meant destroying its content, since the "clean" command wasn't invoked, so I don't think you have lost any data. Have you rebooted your PC and checked the status of SATA in your UEFI? In the BIOS, leave Secure Boot disabled, disable also CSM (Compatibility Support Module) and UEFI mode. If you still get the same error, you'll have to redo your Windows USB stick with MBR instead of GPT, but with the settings I just mentioned, that should do it.

Comment: When I tried accessing the partitions form ubuntu using ubuntu-live I couldn't find some files, I'll try again. I also tried redoing the USB stick and in that case my computer wouldn't even recognize it. I checked the BIOS and all those settings match.

Comment: OK, just to make sure I understand your setup: is your PC using BIOS or UEFI? If both are available (UEFI-mode can be enabled in BIOS on some PCs), which mode is it currently running on? Which mode did you select when you copied Windows onto your USB stick? For that stick to be recognized during boot, and used to install Windows on your PC, it has to be in the same mode as your PC: UEFI (GPT) is you're running on UEFI mode in BIOS or straight UEFI, BIOS (MBR) if you can't enable UEFI in the BIOS on your PC. Any other combination will lead to error messages.

Comment: I used UEFI GPT at first and that worked fine but when I changed to UEFI, BIOS (MBR) it wouldn't recognize the flash drive.

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, it's one or the other, and it must be the same for both your system drive on the PC and the USB drive with the Windows installer. If your PC is UEFI-capable but has a BIOS, you can disable UEFI and "burn" the Windows IOS on an MBR-set USB stick. If your PC is UEFI, period, has no BIOS, just UEFI, then you must "burn" Windows on a UEFI-set USB stick. Rufus can and will do both for you, depending on what you need. If it worked in UEFI mode, then prepare a UEFI version of your stick. You should be able to install Windows 10 then, and from there, repair BCD.

Comment: I was able to transfer a few amount of files using Ubuntu live and then decided to wipe the disk and install windows from the start. It's all working fine now, just the files I couldn't access from C: but it's not a big deal. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, glad your PC is now up-and-running again, and sad because you had to sacrifice some personal data. When you have the time, you might want to fire up Disk Management and get rid of the little unallocated spaces on this drive. It's not just because it's sloppy, but on startup, those partitions are scanned for an existing OS, even though there can't be one of them, and it slows things down.

Comment: I'll make sure to do that. Thank you so much for the help!